# How to display drop-down list-view below particular view in android?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have one filter button.I need to open expandable/dropdown filter same as given below image.I tried popup menu and Listpopup window but,I did not get any success.

[image]

***Thanks in advance***

Comment: May be you can use expandable listview .

Comment: But how?i need exact below button as seen above image.

Comment: expandable listview inside popup window

Comment: can you post some snap of code?

Comment: Here..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785646/how-can-we-add-an-expandablelistview-inside-a-popupwindow-in-android
Redman seem right.

Comment: i never used that, but there are similar questions on So https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800836/expandablelistview-inside-popup  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785646/how-can-we-add-an-expandablelistview-inside-a-popupwindow-in-android

Comment: @Akash verma ,I think it will not display below filter button.i need popup must display below clicked button.

Comment: Thanks to @Aakash Verma ,@Redman,your suggested Link work for me.i am posting my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did code by the help of above comments. but the code looks as below.

```
    final View popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.exp, null);
    listPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(popUpView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
    expandableListView= (ExpandableListView) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    btnticker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
            expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());

            expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
            expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

            listPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of fragment which will be below the filter button,layout will include the ui you expect i.e upper arrow and expandable view or any view you are using..
After clicking on filter just visible the fragment and with fragment transition,for the effect you can use animation too...

This i already done,you can refer carwale app used car section..click on filter button one same dilog will come..

for any thing let me know further..